# Call to virtual function steps into wrong function when called from constructor of derived class, but not when from parent class

Tags: c++, constructor, gdb, virtual-functions

I've got the class structure below (details omitted).

**Environment.h**

```
#include "SimEnv.h"

class Environment : public SimEnv {
public:
  virtual int functionA(int arg) {
    printf("I'm in functionA\n");
    . . .
  }
  virtual int functionB(int arg) {
    printf("I'm in functionB\n");
    . . .
  }
};
```

**DerivedEnv.h**

```
#include "Environment.h"

class DerivedEnv : public Environment {
public:
  DerivedEnv(GrandParentClass* grandpaClass) : Environment() { . . . }
};
```

**ParentClass.h**

```
#include "GrandParentClass.h"
#include "Environment.h"

class ParentClass : public GrandParentClass {
public:
  ParentClass() {
    printf("In ParentClass constructor\n");
    m_pEnv = new DerivedEnv(this);
    m_pEnv->functionB(val);
  }
protected:
  Environment* m_pEnv;

  virtual void thisFunct() {
    printf("Calling functionB from ParentClass::thisFunct()\n");
    m_pEnv->functionB(val);
  }

};
```

**DerivedClass.h**

```
#include "ParentClass.h"

class DerivedClass : public ParentClass {
public:
  DerivedClass() : ParentClass() {
    printf("In DerivedClass constructor\n");
    m_pEnv->functionB(val);
  }
  void thatFunct {
    printf("Calling functionB from DerivedClass::thatFunct()\n");
    m_pEnv->functionB(val);
  }
  void sim() {
    thisFunct();
    printf("Calling functionB from DerivedClass::sim()\n");
    m_pEnv->functionB(val);
  }

};
```

**main.cc**

```
#include "DerivedClass.h"
void main() {
  . . .
  static DerivedClass derivedClass;
  derivedClass.sim();
  . . .
}
```

The problem I have is that when I run my code and I instance DerivedClass, I get the following:

```
In ParentClass constructor
I'm in functionB
In DerivedClass constructor
I'm in functionA
Calling functionB from ParentClass::thisFunct()
I'm in functionB
Calling functionB from DerivedClass::sim()
I'm in functionA
```

So my program is calling the correct virtual function in the constructor of ParentClass but the wrong function immediately afterwards in DerivedClass's constructor. This is what I've checked so far:

1. I've made sure it's not a problem of my build being broken.
2. I've printed out the vtable in gdb using `p /a (*(void ***)m_pEnv)[0]@30` in ParentClass's constructor and in DerivedClass's constructor. Both vtables are shown identical

I've searched on the internet and it seems these types of problems can be due to stack corruption. Is that true? How can I debug it? Is there any other explanation for this problem.

**Addition**
I've debugged further and realised there seems to be a context problem here. When I call functionB from any of ParentClass's member functions, it does execute it correctly.

It seems it's just from DerivedClass that calls go to the wrong function.

I've modified the pseudocode to highlight this.

Comment: Could you please not omit the important details, like `m_pEnv`? Actually, scrap that -- please post real, compilable code, not pseudo-code. Too many annoyances otherwise. Make a minimal, complete example that showcases your problem.

Comment: After fixing all the problems with this pseudo-code, my version prints `I'm in functionB` on both lines. My vote is on "it's broken somewhere else".

Comment: The pseudo code doesn't show any class ever reference functionA, please explain the full pattern with functionA in the real code.

Comment: Thank's for your comments. Unfortunately it wouldn't be practical to post the real code. It is actually part of a multithread Verilog/C++/SystemC cosimulation environment spanning hundreds of files. So it could well be the case that "it's broken somewhere else". I understand it's difficult to give advice without having all the info, I'm not expecting the full solution, I'll be happy with suggestions or ideas on how to proceed for debug.

Comment: The only time I've ever seen the compiler go from one function to another (not different virtual overloads) is when something didn't get recompiled after a virtual function was added in the header.  I would start by double checking the build, even if it means deleting all libraries/objects and starting the build from scratch.

Comment: One other comment: is it possible that you've somehow violated the one definition rule?  Possibly an older copy of a header that was made?

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to call a virtual function from a constructor or a destructor. The reason is that the derived class' object is not complete at that point.

Comment: Not applicable here. They're not called on `this`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going wrong. It was actually quite prosaic. It's a case of having two different version of the same class defined in files with the same filename in different locations.

I think it's a preprocessor issue. I don't fully understand it but here's my tentative explanation.

I've edited the pseudocode above. My directory structure is something similar to this:

```
include/Environment.h
include/DerivedEnv.h
include/Environment.h
include/SimEnv.h
include/ParentClass.h
include/GrandParentClass.h
sim/main.cc
sim/DerivedClass.h
...
distant_remote_directory/SimEnv.h -> this file slightly different from include/SimEnv.h
```

Because distant_remote_directory in in the include path given to g++, main.h picks it up from there. But when compiling ParentClass, since the file SimEnv.h is in the same directory, it gets picked up before the one in distant_remote_directory. So DerivedClass and ParentClass are seeing different versions of the same class.

Thanks everyone for your help.